# Print.css media not fully working

Tags: css

I'm trying to get a few elements on my printing stylesheet to "show" at print/printpreview time and this isn't working.  If I want to 'hide' elements, it works just fine.

I've tried setting the element's `display=block` from `display=none` and this isn't working.  Also tried combinations thereof with using `visibility=visible` from `visibility=hidden`; no luck.

I thought I could work around this by doing some nasty hacking such as having my element at `left= -3000px` to `left=20px`; that change doesn't occur either at print time.

Another ugly hack of mine that isn't working is having the element's font color be the same as the background color in my main stylesheet, then changing it to black at print time; doesn't work either.

However, one thing that does consistently work is hiding any element at print time; so my print.css sheet does get picked up and applied.

In summary, so far, showing an element, changing its font color or position does not get picked up at print time; neither does centering an already visible element with text-align-center; by the way.

Also worth noting: The results are consistent in between IE9 and Chrome.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Does your print stylesheet *follow*, or *precede*, your regular stylesheet? I'm not sure it makes a difference, but try and ensure that print comes last. Just to be sure.

Comment: can you post your print stylesheet or the print styles?

Comment: David, my print.css stylesheet does follow my main one, but good idea.

Comment: @Jason, Did you want me to post the complete contents of my print.css stylesheet in a comment?  In the meantime here is the part where I try to show my element:  .p_divPrintMsg
{
 display:block;
 
}

Comment: @Flood that's a start.  Also, what does the regular CSS that applies also say.  And what does the HTML show.  Three snippets added to your Q would help.

Comment: @Jason.  OK, your question about my main CSS got me thinking and I realised that I used an inline style for that element instead of setting its default in my main CSS; we may have a specificity issue here.  I'm doing a quick test and if it's negative I will post your requested info.  Thank you.

Comment: @Jason.  I'll be darned.  The inline style as the default instead of the CSS was the culprit.  I moved the default style for that element from 'inline' over to my main CSS and now the print CSS applies it correctly.  Thank you for your help.  Do I do anything to flag this question as answered or as something else?  BTW as far as you know should other styles such as centering and fonts also be applied by a  printing stylesheet?

Comment: Glad you figured out.  I can put a quick answer below and you can mark it as answered.  Or, you can answer it yourself and check your own answer.

Comment: As for centering and fonts, anything you want to style exclusively for print should appear in your print.css

Comment: Check the `media` attribute on your primary stylesheet.. it should be set to `screen`. If it's blank, it uses the default value of `all`, which means it will still be loaded when printing.

Comment: @jnpcl OK thank you.  I'll run some tests on that and go from there.

Comment: @Flood... thanks, this worked perfectly for me.. the only thing to add was to position:absolute... but apart from that, perfect.. thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check to see that any inline styles are not conflicting with your main css and your print styles.

Comment: I guess we can chalk this up to a bit of a joint effort; though I definitely would not have thought about checking for specificity of the styles for quite a long time if it weren't for your input.  I actually had spent probably close to 10 hours trying to get this going before posting the question here.  Thank you Jason.

Answer (score 1):

An ugly workaround may be to add the `!important` tag to the print.css style.

Example:

```
.element {
    display: block !important;
}
```

Comment: Amazing to me this tag even exists.  I didn't know it did.  If it works as  you mention it probably would have worked as well.  Thank you.

Comment: I guess, when you want to override some style in the normal css with print css you would have to add !important.